# Visual Basic .NET - Change color of one listBox item

Tags: vb.net, text, colors, listbox

I'm making a small program in VB.NET. I have a listBox and a button. I'd like to be able to press the button and have the selected listBox item change it's foreColor to green. I've tried many ways of doing this, ranging from overriding the draw method to using a listView (listBox is much better for what I'm doing, please don't recommend that I use a listView, I've already tried it.)

At first I thought this would be simple, but it's the exact opposite and I'm very frustrated that such a simple task should be so difficult. I don't want to use any third-party controls, as I'd have to completely re-write my application.

I've tried so many different options it's not even funny. Please, can anyone offer a simpler solution?

-Q

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle **DrawItem** event and **DrawMode=OwnerDrawFixed** property.

```
Dim buttonPressed As Boolean
Private Sub ListBox1_DrawItem(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs) Handles ListBox1.DrawItem
    e.DrawBackground()

    If ListBox1.SelectedIndices.Contains(e.Index) And buttonPressed Then
        e.Graphics.DrawString(ListBox1.Items(e.Index), e.Font, Brushes.Green, e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y)

    Else
        e.Graphics.DrawString(ListBox1.Items(e.Index), e.Font, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y)
    End If
    If e.Index = ListBox1.Items.Count - 1 Then
        buttonPressed = False
    End If
    e.DrawFocusRectangle()
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    buttonPressed = True
    ListBox1.Refresh()
End Sub
```

Comment: Draw the focus rectangle *after* drawing the string.  Using TextRenderer.DrawText is recommended.

Comment: Using this exact code, I get this error:  InvalidArgument=Value of '-1' is not valid for 'index'.
Parameter name: index

Comment: @Quark: This code is for your reference, please put appropriate control statement to avoid such problems. I haven't tested this code.

Comment: I have modified it to fit my control, it is telling me that the index is invalid. I have tried similar code and I get the same error.