# Setting listbox item (by index) font bold

Tags: vb.net, fonts, listbox, listboxitems

I'm trying to set all current available items in a `listbox` to font bold. And when there are items added at a later time they will have the default font. So the user can visibly see the initial listed items and the new ones.

From the form constructor I fill my listbox like this, these are the initial values that are added.

```
Private Sub FillLinkedBox(ByVal oReferenceList As String())

    ' Fill the linked listbox with the current linked items
    Debug.Print(oReferenceList.ToString)
    lbLinkedParameters.Items.AddRange(oReferenceList)

    ' Set the font of all the existing items in the listbox
    For i As Integer = 0 To lbLinkedParameters.Items.Count - 1

       ' Set the font to bold for these items.

    Next

End Sub
```

After the user is finished I would also like to test the items font when processing so I can determinate what was an initial value and what not (but I could also keep the list in memory and check if the item is listed) if the font checking is not a good option.

If found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240612/visual-basic-net-change-color-of-one-listbox-item) that describes something that should do this operation, but it's based on an event; and I don't understand how it works.

```
Dim buttonPressed As Boolean
Private Sub ListBox1_DrawItem(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs) Handles ListBox1.DrawItem
e.DrawBackground()

    If ListBox1.SelectedIndices.Contains(e.Index) And buttonPressed Then
        e.Graphics.DrawString(ListBox1.Items(e.Index), e.Font, Brushes.Green, e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y)

    Else
        e.Graphics.DrawString(ListBox1.Items(e.Index), e.Font, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y)
    End If
    If e.Index = ListBox1.Items.Count - 1 Then
        buttonPressed = False
    End If
    e.DrawFocusRectangle()
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    buttonPressed = True
    ListBox1.Refresh()
End Sub
```

My question is : how do I change the font of a listbox item at given index?

Comment: Try using a Datagridview instead. It's easier to format rows and cells

Comment: True, but it can be done with a `ListBox` with relatively low difficulty.

Answer (score 1):

`it's based on an event; and I don't understand how it works.`

If you set a ListControl (List/Combo) to `OwnerDraw`, the `DrawItem` event is fired each time Windows needs to draw an item; you can supply the code to change the color, Font or do other things.

`After the user is finished I would also like to test the items font when processing`

The problem is that the font is based on a state for an item.  As you described it, that is whether the item is Original or Added.  That state cannot be determined from the index, nor can you later re-determine that state from a visual element such as the way something *was* drawn (nor should you).

So the task at hand is really 2 related things:

1. Show the user which items are new/added
2. Track them somehow so the code can determine them

This will use an interface which you can add to any class.  This makes the solution less specific to this one localized case.

```
Public Interface IListItem
    Property Selected As Boolean
    Function GetDisplayText() As String  ' not really needed
End Interface
```

The code will use `Selected` to track and draw the added items.  Change the name if you wish, but you will also have to change the draw code.

```
Public Class SimpleThing
    Implements IListItem

    ' your stuff
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Value As Int32
    Public Property Foo As Int32
    Public Property Bar As Single     

    Public Property Selected As Boolean Implements IListItem.Selected

    Public Sub New(n As String, v As Int32, 
                Optional b As Boolean = True)
        Name = n
        Value = v
        Selected = b
    End Sub

    Public Function GetDisplayText() As String Implements IListItem.GetDisplayText
        Return Name
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Name
    End Function
End Class
```

`GetDisplayText` is to allow a different text output when the item is displayed in a ListControl versus other situations.  It is not a hard requirement.

The `SimpleThing` could store whatever info about these things you need, the `ListBox`/`ComboBox` drawing only relies on the `IListItem` elements.  You can populate the control by using a List as the `DataSource`:

```
ListThings = New List(Of SimpleThing)
...
ListThings.Add(New SimpleThing("Able", 42, True))
ListThings.Add(New SimpleThing("Baker", 7, True))
...
ListThings.Add(New SimpleThing("Ziggy", 6, True))

lbEnabler.DataSource = ListThings
lbEnabler.DisplayMember = "Name"
lbEnabler.ValueMember = "Value"
```

The UI control is set to `OwnerDrawFixed` and uses this code to draw the items:

```
Private Sub lst_DrawItem(sender As Object, 
                    e As DrawItemEventArgs) Handles lbEnabler.DrawItem
    Dim lb As ListBox = CType(sender, ListBox)
    If e.Index < 0 Then
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, "", lb.Font, e.Bounds, lb.ForeColor)
        Return
    End If

    Dim bg As Color = If(e.State.HasFlag(DrawItemState.Selected),
                         SystemColors.Highlight, SystemColors.Window)
    Dim fg As Color = If(e.State.HasFlag(DrawItemState.Selected),
                         SystemColors.HighlightText, SystemColors.WindowText)

    Dim iItem As IListItem
    If TypeOf lb.Items(e.Index) Is IListItem Then
        iItem = CType(lb.Items(e.Index), IListItem)
    Else
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, lb.Items(e.Index).ToString, lb.Font, e.Bounds,
                              fg, bg, TextFormatFlags.Left Or
                              TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter)
        Return
    End If
    e.DrawBackground()

    If iItem.Selected Then            ' change to IsOrginal or IsBold
        Using f As New Font(lb.Font.FontFamily, lb.Font.Size, FontStyle.Bold)
            TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, iItem.GetDisplayText(), f, e.Bounds,
                                  fg, bg, TextFormatFlags.Left Or
                                  TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter)
        End Using
    Else
        '  default
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, iItem.GetDisplayText(), lb.Font, e.Bounds,
                              fg, bg, TextFormatFlags.Left Or
                              TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter)
    End If

End Sub
```

Result:

[image]

Personally, I dont think it is a very good presentation.  It is non-standard and what the **Bold** represents is not immediately obvious.  However, you can do whatever you want in the `DrawItem` event such as add a graphic indicator:

[image]

The green plus version makes it pretty clear which ones were added.  Getting which items were added also simply a matter of polling the items collection:

```
Dim added = myListBox.Items.
                Cast(Of SimpleThing).
                Where(Function(f) f.Selected).
                ToArray()
```

Comment: If this answers the question please click the checkmark so this is moved off the Unanswered list.